# Qt 5.1 Quick Controls Deployment error

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I try to deploy my Qt 5.1 application on Windows and get an error while running window with Qt Quick Controls component. Window is not shown, it look like white rectangle.

My Bundle structure:

- imageformats

  - qgif.dll
  - qico.dll
- platforms

  - qminimal.dll
  - qwindows.dll
- QtQuick
- QtQuick.2
- QtWebkit
- icudt51.dll
- icuin51.dll
- icuuc51.dll
- libeay32.dll
- libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
- libstdc++-6.dll
- libwinpthread-1.dll
- Qt5Core.dll
- Qt5Gui.dll
- Qt5Network.dll
- Qt5OpenGL.dll
- Qt5PrintSupport.dll
- Qt5Qml.dll
- Qt5Quick.dll
- Qt5Sensors.dll
- Qt5Sql.dll
- Qt5V8.dll
- Qt5WebKit.dll
- Qt5WebKitWidgets.dll
- Qt5Widgets.dll
- Qt5Xml.dll
- Qt5XmlPatterns.dll
- MyApp.exe
- ssleay32.dll

QtQuick, QtQuick.2, QtWebkit are folders from \Qt5.1.0\5.1.0\mingw48_32\qml\

Error:

```
    qrc:/qml/resources/qml/SettingsDialog.qml:775:21: Type RadioButton unavailable
file://%myApp%/QtQuick/Controls/RadioButton.qml:80:1: Type AbstractCheckable unavailable 
     AbstractCheckable {

     ^ 
file://%myApp%/QtQuick/Controls/Private/AbstractCheckable.qml:61:1: Control is not a type 
     Control {
```

Comment: do you still have this issue?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to update this issue in time. The problem was in place of bundle: it was launched from network drive in VMWare virtual machine. I moved it to local drive and it works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in place of bundle: it was launched from network drive in VMWare virtual machine. I moved it to local drive and it works.

Comment: i have the similar problem, but i don't get solution, you can maybe post image of your directory?

Answer (score 0):

This is a QT bug, the only solution that i found is to add `import QtQuick.Controls.Private 1.0` in `AbstractCheckable.qml`